# How to to get currernt viewed text of web page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, text, screen

Is there any JS functionality to get the text that is currently viewed by a user?

**Assume there is a page with some text (or a lot of text) and I need some javascript-written black box that can retrieve text (any text within *div, p, span* ... or any other tags) that is currently visible on user's screen.**

This should take in account the fact that user can scroll the page, only currently viewed text must be retrieved.

Is that possible with javascript?

**How can this be implemeneted? (primarily for use in Firefox)**

Do you know any js library that provides this functionality???

Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/kuHHw/

I'm using jquery with the [viewport](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) selector plugin. The example shows the visible div's in green and appends the innerHTML into the span at the bottom of the page

Comment: And what about productivity?

Can this approach be run in FF extension every second or even more often?